# Which is faster in MYSQL UPDATE, IF statement or CASE statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update, case-statement

I'm testing query's speed in mysql 5.7.

1.

```
UPDATE tablefortest SET testbit = CASE WHEN TEST_YN = 'Y' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END;
```

2. 

```
UPDATE tablefortest SET testbit = IF(TEST_YN LIKE 'Y', '1', '0');
```

Both query take a time 0.8sec ~ 1.1sec. Sometimes IF statement is faster and the other times CASE statement is faster. I wonder the difference between two queries's running principle. And how can I make query speed faster???

Thanks.

Comment: The most fast is `UPDATE tablefortest SET testbit = (TEST_YN = 'Y');` - it removes excess compare and reassign. But if `TEST_YN` is NULL then it will set `testbit` to NULL, not to zero... PS. CASE and IF does not differ in performance. More precisely, the difference is less that measuring accuracy. Moreover, I doubt that you can detect the improvement of my query usage - by the same reason.

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot! I should change engine settings or other factors.

Comment: If speed is the concern, just execute two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps faster:

```
UPDATE tablefortest SET testbit = TEST_YN = 'Y';
```

But...  Having redundant information is a no-no.

Other approaches, each of which *eliminates* that big `UPDATE`:

- When the value of `TEST_YN` is changed, change `testbit` at the same time
- Use a `TRIGGER` for the previous comment
- Use a "GENERATED" column

Answer (score -1):

"Why do you [have to ...] care?"

The execution-speed of any SQL query ... at any time when that query is executed ... depends on a very wide variety of environmental factors.  So, why are you concerned with a difference of 3 milliseconds?

Comment: That record is in my local environment with 24000 rows data, and i should fix the server's slow-query issue.. In server, there are almost 9millions rows of data. I can't test on server so test in local and adjust the better query to server. I know vague there are many factors to affect to query time, but the server is live and commercial so I can't test all of the factors on server. So I'll upgrade query and if it doesn't work, then I will try to test other factors

Comment: sorry for make you confuse, that I didn't tell my situation and not good English